# What is the best / fastest way to validate this string format "A000AA00" in PHP?

Tags: php, regex

I need to verify that my string `$path` contains exactly 8 characters and that `$path` is in the following pattern: `A000AA00` where A is any letter A-Z and 0 is any number 0-9.

The first thing I did was that I used `strlen` to get the string length.

```
if (strlen($path) !== 8) { die('Bad string length'); }
```

Next I used `ctype_alpha` and `ctype_digit` to check if the string is in the format I want based on what I expect `$path[0-7]` to be.

```
if (ctype_alpha($path[0]) && ctype_digit($path[1]) && ctype_digit($path[2]) && ctype_digit($path[3]) && ctype_alpha($path[4]) && ctype_alpha($path[5]) && ctype_digit($path[6]) && ctype_digit($path[7])) { // We good }
```

Could I improve this code somehow?
Are there any faster alternatives?

Comment: Try `preg_match('~^[A-Z]\d{3}[A-Z]{2}\d{2}\z~', $s)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I'll try that and compare the difference. Is preg_match a faster alternative?

Comment: It's trivial to benchmark preg_match against your existing code but I'll wager you'll find the results irrelevant. Don't pre-optimize for a problem you're not even sure you have.

Comment: if (ctype_alpha($path[0].$path[4].$path[5]) && ctype_digit($path[1].$path[2].$path[3].$path[6].$path[7]) ) { // We good }

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to use a regex to validate such a pattern, you may try

```
preg_match('~^[A-Z]\d{3}[A-Z]{2}\d{2}\z~', $s)
```

The regex approach is very readable: start with an uppercase letter, 3 digits, 2 uppercase letters, 2 digits, end of the string.

Now,

```
$path = "A000AA00";
$startA = microtime(true);
for($i = 0; $i < 100000; $i++)
{
  if (strlen($path) !== 8) { die('Bad string length'); }
  if (ctype_alpha($path[0]) && ctype_digit($path[1]) && ctype_digit($path[2]) && ctype_digit($path[3]) && ctype_alpha($path[4]) && ctype_alpha($path[5]) && ctype_digit($path[6]) && ctype_digit($path[7])) { // We good 
  }
}
$endA = microtime(true);
echo $endA-$startA;
```

[yields](https://3v4l.org/NXbdP) `0.02226710319519` (PHP 7.3.2), and the regex based solution [yields](https://3v4l.org/ZONs1) `0.0064888000488281`.